# Web Server Processes sticking at Sending Reply

Tags: linux, freebsd

I have a web server that has a lot of processes getting stuck at sending reply.
This occurs on numerous pages that are created from different CMS systems in use so a single php script issue seems to be unlikely and we think it is more due to a server configuration problem.

When the list builds up the server starts to slow down and we have to reset it to clear it out.

Can anyone recommend anything I should be checking to try and prevent this from happening.

```
Restart Time: Tuesday, 19-Feb-2013 03:00:17 GMT
Parent Server Generation: 0
Server uptime: 6 hours 22 minutes 49 seconds
Total accesses: 4081 - Total Traffic: 83.2 MB
CPU Usage: u76.5313 s37.1563 cu0 cs0 - .495% CPU load
.178 requests/sec - 3798 B/second - 20.9 kB/request
43 requests currently being processed, 3 idle workers
WW_WWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWRWWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWWWWWWWWWWW..................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process

Srv PID Acc M   CPU SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
0-0 97917   0/12/414    W   2.13    120 0   0.0 0.55    7.62    123.151.139.215 www.-------.co.uk   GET / HTTP/1.1
1-0 97882   0/3/236 W   3.52    139 0   0.0 0.00    10.01   82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/search.php?action=AjaxSearch&search_query=georgie HTT
2-0 97883   0/40/124    _   13.03   67  106075  0.0 1.37    2.87    180.76.5.162    www.-------.co.uk   GET /visually_impaired/zoomtext/zoomtext_magnifier_reader/ HTTP
3-0 97884   0/52/258    W   5.68    64  0   0.0 1.12    11.10   204.12.208.218  www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/cart.php?action=add&product_id=177 HTTP/1.0
4-0 97918   5/6/337 W   1.30    159 0   21.2    0.02    5.52    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /scripts/styleswitcher.js HTTP/1.1
5-0 97907   1/11/322    W   0.60    174 0   8.6 0.38    4.81    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /scripts/styleswitcher.js HTTP/1.1
6-0 97875   0/35/362    W   5.34    113 0   0.0 0.60    4.60    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/search.php?action=AjaxSearch&search_query=georgie%20
7-0 97876   3/64/366    W   5.45    171 0   7.8 0.49    5.13    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /scripts/styleswitcher.js HTTP/1.1
8-0 97910   0/31/331    W   0.28    123 0   0.0 1.10    5.67    66.249.76.180   www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=JAWS-Remote-Access-Add%252dOn-fo
9-0 97911   0/26/219    W   5.34    108 0   0.0 1.43    5.14    176.9.16.210    www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=JAWS-Professional-%252d-Upgrades
10-0    97767   0/76/243    W   24.87   9   0   0.0 0.71    2.81    157.55.33.79    www.-------.co.uk   GET /?p=975 HTTP/1.1
11-0    97935   0/0/109 W   3.70    82  0   0.0 0.00    3.69    66.249.76.180   www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=JAWS-Multi%252dUser-Products HTT
12-0    97919   0/6/141 W   1.66    140 0   0.0 0.02    2.66    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/search.php?action=AjaxSearch&search_query=georgie HTT
13-0    97914   2/2/104 W   1.14    168 0   11.3    0.01    1.41    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /scripts/styleswitcher.js HTTP/1.1
14-0    97650   0/100/112   _   23.39   66  95416   0.0 2.41    2.73    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /scripts/styleswitcher.js HTTP/1.1
15-0    97927   0/0/154 W   0.09    140 0   0.0 0.00    2.32    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/search.php?action=AjaxSearch&search_query=geor HTTP/1
16-0    97921   1/1/93  W   0.59    156 0   0.0 0.00    2.13    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /scripts/styleswitcher.js HTTP/1.1
17-0    97922   1/1/36  W   0.88    163 0   11.7    0.01    0.43    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /scripts/styleswitcher.js HTTP/1.1
18-0    97923   0/3/29  W   1.35    23  0   0.0 0.02    1.06    204.12.208.218  www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/cart.php?action=add&product_id=202 HTTP/1.0
19-0    97924   0/9/50  R   1.29    124 63  0.0 0.02    0.71    ?   ?   ..reading..
20-0    97925   0/11/14 W   1.93    98  0   0.0 0.10    0.11    176.9.16.210    www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=OpenBook-User-Guide HTTP/1.0
21-0    97926   0/6/6   W   0.25    117 0   0.0 0.42    0.42    176.9.16.210    www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=Imperial-Tactile-Ruler-(inch) HT
22-0    97928   0/0/0   W   0.00    139 0   0.0 0.00    0.00    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/search.php?search_query=georgie&x=0&y=0 HTTP/1.1
23-0    97929   0/4/4   W   0.27    126 0   0.0 0.07    0.07    176.9.16.210    www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php HTTP/1.0
24-0    97930   0/2/2   W   1.27    88  0   0.0 0.01    0.01    176.9.16.210    www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=RUBY-Reading-Stand HTTP/1.0
25-0    97931   0/6/6   W   0.29    76  0   0.0 0.11    0.11    204.12.208.218  www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/cart.php?action=add&product_id=157 HTTP/1.0
26-0    97932   0/1/1   W   1.45    52  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    65.55.52.86 www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=Voice-Sense- HTTP/1.1
27-0    97933   0/1/1   W   0.23    65  0   0.0 0.01    0.01    176.9.16.210    www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=TOPAZ-XL-Computer-Compatible-Des
28-0    97934   0/1/1   W   1.61    53  0   0.0 0.01    0.01    176.9.16.210    www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=TOPAZ-XL-HD HTTP/1.0
29-0    97936   0/0/0   W   0.00    79  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    176.9.16.210    www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=TOPAZ-EZ-Desktop-Video-Magnifier
30-0    97937   0/0/0   W   0.00    60  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    65.55.52.86 www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/pages.php?pageid=10 HTTP/1.1
31-0    97938   0/1/1   _   1.39    62  13532   0.0 0.02    0.02    84.21.142.136   www.-------.co.uk   GET / HTTP/1.0
32-0    97939   0/2/2   W   1.74    42  0   0.0 0.02    0.02    204.12.208.218  www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/cart.php?action=add&product_id=179 HTTP/1.0
33-0    97940   0/1/1   W   0.68    52  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    204.12.208.218  www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/cart.php?action=add&product_id=178 HTTP/1.0
34-0    97953   1/1/1   W   0.18    39  0   0.2 0.00    0.00    109.157.238.155 www.-------.co.uk   GET /team.exe HTTP/1.1
35-0    97954   0/0/0   W   0.00    38  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    65.55.52.86 www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/pages.php?pageid=10 HTTP/1.0
36-0    97955   0/0/0   W   0.00    37  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    209.85.238.127  www.-------.co.uk   GET /?feed=rss&cat=4 HTTP/1.1
37-0    97956   0/1/1   W   0.78    12  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    204.12.208.218  www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/cart.php?action=add&product_id=206 HTTP/1.0
38-0    97957   0/0/0   W   0.00    34  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    204.12.208.218  www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/cart.php?action=add&product_id=199 HTTP/1.0
39-0    97958   0/0/0   W   0.00    6   0   0.0 0.00    0.00    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /?cat=3 HTTP/1.1
40-0    97959   0/0/0   W   0.00    12  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /?cat=3 HTTP/1.1
41-0    97962   0/0/0   W   0.00    9   0   0.0 0.00    0.00    65.55.52.86 www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/products.php?product=Voice-Sense- HTTP/1.0
42-0    97963   0/0/0   W   0.00    2   0   0.0 0.00    0.00    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET / HTTP/1.1
43-0    97964   0/0/0   W   0.00    0   0   0.0 0.00    0.00    82.68.11.50 www.-------.co.uk   GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
44-0    97965   0/0/0   W   0.00    0   0   0.0 0.00    0.00    204.12.208.218  www.-------.co.uk   GET /shop/cart.php?action=add&product_id=208 HTTP/1.0
45-0    97966   0/0/0   W   0.00    0   0   0.0 0.00    0.00    95.211.87.85    www.-------.co.uk   GET /quotes/ HTTP/1.0
Srv Child Server number - generation
PID OS process ID
Acc Number of accesses this connection / this child / this slot
M   Mode of operation
CPU CPU usage, number of seconds
SS  Seconds since beginning of most recent request
Req Milliseconds required to process most recent request
Conn    Kilobytes transferred this connection
Child   Megabytes transferred this child
Slot    Total megabytes transferred this slot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is one of them logging excessively from PHP?  That could slow down all other processes trying to log anything to the `php.log`.

Comment: The server does log an awful lot of data.

Comment: Reducing the amount of information logged has solved the issue. No lockups since.